# How to convert input to string and find the index of the first two characters?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first time posting here since I haven't been able to find a specific answer for my question anywhere so apologies if I'm doing something wrong.

Anyway, I wanted to know if there was a way to convert text from a form input to a string and grab a substring of that text?

For example if I have a form input like this:

```
 <form onsubmit="return formValidation()">
     <input type="text" name="foo">
 </form>
```

Can I grab whatever is typed into that input like so?

```
function myFunction() {
     var string = document.getElementByName('foo').value;
     // Code converting the selected element to a string
     var index = string.substring(0, 2);
     // Rest of code
}
```

I have little experience in JavaScript so I'm confused on how to convert an element to string. jQuery solutions are welcome.

I wanted to do this for an ID number validation on a form, which basically checks the first two indexes of an 8-digit ID number to see if it's a known ID number in my school district.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Okay so since people actually saw this, could anyone tell me what's wrong with this code? It's returning false even for numbers starting with the numbers here.

```
function formValidation() {
var idInput = document.getElementsByName('idNumber')[0].value;
var idNumber = idInput.substring(0, 2);

if(idNumber === "71" || idNumber === "81" || idNumber === "53") {
    alert("Your form has been submitted. You will now be redirected to a confirmation page.");
    return true;
} else {
    alert("Please input a valid ID number. If the first two integers of your ID do not match the school district standard, contact a club leader.");
    return false;
}
```

}

Is the method I'm using to compare strings wrong?

Comment: Where did you invoked `formValidation()`?. In the html I didn't find any relevant code that indicates function was invoked or executed on some event.

Comment: @Arvind my bad, forgot! Just edited it.

Comment: Have a look at my updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is: `document.getElementByName('foo').value`, you have missed `s`

```
document.getElementsByName('foo')
                   ^
```

`document.getElementsByName('foo')` gives you `NodeList`, not just a single HtmlElement,

Use instead:

`document.getElementsByName('foo')[0].value;`

**Edited:** Have a look at below functional code.

```js
function formValidation() {
  var idInput = document.getElementsByName('idNumber')[0].value;
  var idNumber = idInput.substring(0, 2);

  if (idNumber === "71" || idNumber === "81" || idNumber === "53") {
    alert("Your form has been submitted. You will now be redirected to a confirmation page.");
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Please input a valid ID number. If the first two integers of your ID do not match the school district standard, contact a club leader.");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return formValidation();">
  <input type="text" name="idNumber" autofocus="" value="71456" maxlength="8" />
</form>
```

Comment: I am glad it helped

Comment: If you want to mark this question as answered, just click that green check  mark next to this answer!